# Update combobox values from txt file

Tags: python, function, tkinter, combobox

Here are my aims with these three functions;

- "Add" function add Entry values to a .txt file
- "ValueSource" open/create a .txt file and sort its values
- "GetUpdatedValues" function to assign the values from the .txt file as the Combobox values.

> ```
> def Add():
>     with open('ComboValues.txt', 'a+') as file:
>     file.write('\n'+(str(SubKey1.get())+'\n'+(str(Subkey2.get()))))
>     file.close
>
> def ValueSource():
>     with open('ComboValues.txt') as inFile:
>         ComboboxValue = [line for line in inFile]
>         ComboboxValue = sorted(ComboboxValue)
>
> def GetUpdatedValues():
>     Values = ValueSource()
>     Root.Combobox['values'] = Values
> ```

Here is the Tkinter part of the code where I am using the 'postcommand' method on the Combobox

```
class GUI ():
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.EntryMainKey = Entry(Root, textvariable= MainKey).grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
    master.EntrySubKey1 = Entry(Root, textvariable= SubKey1).grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
    master.EntrySubKey2 = Entry(Root, textvariable= Subkey2).grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
    master.AddButton = Button(Root, text='Add', command=Add).grid(row=3, column=0)
    master.Combobox = Combobox(Root, state='normal', postcommand=GetUpdatedValues)
    master.Combobox.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)

def main():
    GUI(Root)
    ValueSource()
    Root.mainloop()
```

The 'Add' function works. The issue I'm having is how to assign the Combobox values each time a new entry value is appended to the .txt file. I'm unsure of the correct way to address the 'ValueSource' function from inside the 'GetUpdatedValues function'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need `return ComboBoxValue` in `ValueSource()`.

Comment: Why are you using `master.EntryMainKey`, `master.EntrySubKey1`, ...? I suggest you look at some object oriented programming tutorials. This isn't a good way of using classes.